# Как использовать 2 переменные в одном цикле?

Tags: python-3.x

```
            parsed_contract_num = '<loan_data>договор № 0101-000056-26/00 от 31.07.2019; рекомендуемая сумма платежа: 145363.00 сом</loan_data>,<loan_data>договор № 0101-000056-25/00 от 16.05.2019; рекомендуемая сумма платежа: 35911.00 сом</loan_data>'
            contract_nums = re.findall(r'договор № (\S{14})', parsed_contract_num)
            recommended_amount = re.findall(r'платежа:(\S{11})', parsed_contract_num)
            r = '<br>'
            for i in range(len(contract_nums)):
                req = contract_nums[i]
                rec_amount = recommended_amount[i]
                r += """
                <button onclick="obj.select('%s', '%s');" class="fincabank_button">№: %s Сумма: 
                 %s
                </button>""" % (req, req, req, rec_amount)
                buttons_div.setInnerXml(r)
```

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы 2-переменная получила свое значение? Данное время переменная req отлично работает(обрезанную символы показывает норм в кнопке. А вот 2 переменная пусто([]). Было бы хорошо без дополнительных библиотек решать данный вопрос. Спасибо. 2 кнопки должны быть. Пример одной кнопки должен быть так: № 0101-000056-25 Сумма: 35911.00 сом.

Comment: Вопрос непонятен.

Answer (score 0):

```
parsed_contract_num = '<loan_data>договор № 0101-000056-26/00 от 31.07.2019; рекомендуемая сумма платежа: 145363.00 сом</loan_data>,<loan_data>договор № 0101-000056-25/00 от 16.05.2019; рекомендуемая сумма платежа: 35911.00 сом</loan_data>'

contract_nums = re.findall(r'договор № (\S{14})', parsed_contract_num)
recommended_amount = re.findall(r'платежа: (\S{8})', parsed_contract_num)

for i in range(len(contract_nums)):
    req = contract_nums[i]
    rec_amount = recommended_amount[i]
    r = """
    <br>
    <button onclick="obj.select('%s', '%s');" class="fincabank_button">
        №: %s Сумма: %s
    </button>""" % (req, req, req, rec_amount)

    #buttons_div.setInnerXml(r)      ? buttons_div
    print(r)
```

---

```
<br>
<button onclick="obj.select('0101-000056-26', '0101-000056-26');" class="fincabank_button">
    №: 0101-000056-26 Сумма: 145363.0
</button>

<br>
<button onclick="obj.select('0101-000056-25', '0101-000056-25');" class="fincabank_button">
    №: 0101-000056-25 Сумма: 35911.00
</button>
```

Comment: Видимо о существовании пробела я забыл... проверю и отпишусь